# Having and issue plotting horizontal chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotting

So for some weird reason I can't manage to fix the plotting issue

Any suggestions?

[image]

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

List = [] 
for i in range(len(model)):
  cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, model[i].predict(X_test))

  TN = cm[0][0]
  TP = cm[1][1]
  FN = cm[1][0]
  FP = cm[0][1]

  List.append(((TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FN + FP))*100)

  print()

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ('Logistic', 'K Nearest Neighbor', 'K Nearest Neighbor', 'Support Vector Machine ', 'Support Vector Machine ','Support Vector Machine ','Support Vector Machine ' )
percentage = np.array([List[0], List[1], List[2], List[3],List[4],List[5],List[6]])


new_labels = [i+'  {:.2f}%'.format(j) for i, j in zip(bars, percentage)]

plt.barh(bars, percentage, color='lightskyblue', edgecolor='blue')
plt.yticks(range(len(bars)), new_labels)
# Show graphic
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello @Omerlewitz, welcome to the site. Your answer seems quite vague, have a look [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask better questions.
Nevertheless, could you describe better what your *desired outcome* would be?

Comment: each algorithm will be filled to the percentage it should be and the bar will be blue Like the bottom ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change one line in your code.

This

`plt.barh(bars, percentage, color='lightskyblue', edgecolor='blue')`

should become this

`plt.barh(range(len(bars)), percentage, color='lightskyblue', edgecolor='blue')`

What you are changing is the `y` position of your bars. If you look at your original `bars` there are only 3 values there, so bars were overlapping.

Once you change that to  `range(len(bars))` you are using the same tick values that you set in `plt.yticks(range(len(bars)), new_labels)`.

[image]